# Package Conversion - Oracle to PostgreSQL migration

Tags: postgresql

I am new to Postgres. We are migrating an Oracle db to Postgres. In Oracle we have used so many packages.  As per my understanding, there is no Oracle package like functionality in Postgres. I was just trying to find some way to 
migrate Oracle packages to Postgres. And in Oracle package, global variables are there.

Please let me know your comments on this - (this is for creating a package named NP_AC015_FETCH).

```
      create or replace package NP_AC015_FETCH is

      function FUNC_GET_DATA(P_OUT_CUR out SYS_REFCURSOR) return varchar2;
      function FUNC_GET_DATA_AUTO(P_OUT_CUR out SYS_REFCURSOR) return varchar2;

      --Added 2006/12/07 - start
       PV_LOG_START_MODE constant pls_integer := 0;  
       PV_LOG_RUNNING_MODE constant pls_integer := 1;  
       PV_LOG_CLOSE_MODE constant pls_integer := 2;  
       PV_LOG_ERR_CODE constant pls_integer := -20001;

    procedure PROC_LOG(P_MSG in VARCHAR2, P_MODE in pls_integer default PV_LOG_RUNNING_MODE);

    end NP_AC015_FETCH;
    /

    create or replace package body NP_AC015_FETCH is

      --Log file
      GM_LOG_FILE  UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;

      --String and SQL Keyword
      GM_Q constant CHAR := '''';
      GM_L constant CHAR := CHR(10);
      GM_T constant CHAR := CHR(9);

      --alias name
      GM_A_HKNSMK constant CHAR(8) := '保険種目';
      GM_A_HKNSYR constant CHAR(8) := '保険種類';
      GM_A_DISP constant CHAR(6) := '表示置';
      GM_A_CNT constant CHAR(6) := '契約数';
      GM_A_HKNKGK constant CHAR(8) := '保険金額';

      GM_ERR_LINE       varchar2(4000); 
      GM_HANDLED   boolean := false; 
      GM_ERRORSTACK     varchar2(2000); 
      GM_CALLSTACK      varchar2(2000); 
      GM_FORMATTED_STACK varchar2(10000); 

      function FUNC_HEAD_STMT return varchar2;
      function FUNC_END_STMT return varchar2;
      procedure PROC_SUB_LOG(P_MSG in varchar2);
      procedure PROC_SUB_ERR(P_ERR_LINE varchar2, P_ERR_STACK varchar2, P_CALL_STACK varchar2, P_HANDLE boolean);


      /**
       * Saving Error Information Procedure
       * Parameters:
       *  P_ERR_LINE -> DBMS_UTILITY.format_error_backtrace
       *  P_ERR_STACK -> DBMS_UTILITY.format_error_stack
       *  P_CALL_STACK -> DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_CALL_STACK
       *  P_HANDLE -> If true, error message will create
       */
      procedure PROC_SUB_ERR(P_ERR_LINE varchar2,
                    P_ERR_STACK varchar2,
                    P_CALL_STACK  varchar2,
                    P_HANDLE      boolean) is
      begin

        /*Save the first call_stack, error_stack at the first instant, ignore the further tracing*/
        if not GM_HANDLED then

          GM_ERR_LINE   := P_ERR_LINE;
          GM_HANDLED    := true;
          GM_ERRORSTACK := P_ERR_STACK;
          GM_CALLSTACK  := P_CALL_STACK;

        end if;

        /*THIS BLOCK IS EXECUTED AT BOTTOM MOST PROCEDURE IN THE STACK HIERARCHY*/
        if P_HANDLE then
          GM_FORMATTED_STACK := CHR(10) ||'==============================================================' ||
                              CHR(10) || 'Error Stack:' || 
                              CHR(10) || GM_ERR_LINE  || 
                              CHR(10) || GM_ERRORSTACK || 
                              CHR(10) || 'CALL Stack:' ||
                              CHR(10) || gm_CALLSTACK || 
                              CHR(10) ||
                              '==============================================================';
        end if;

      end PROC_SUB_ERR;

      /**
       * Procedure for output Log messages to a file (External Interface)
       * Parameters:
       *  P_MSG → Output message
       *  P_MODE → Mode：Start=0,Processing=1, End=2
       */
        procedure PROC_LOG(P_MSG in VARCHAR2, P_MODE in pls_integer default PV_LOG_RUNNING_MODE) as

            V_F_IS_OPEN boolean;      --IF LOG FILE IS ALREADY OPEN THIS IS SET TO TRUE
            V_LOG_MSG varchar2(32767); --LOG FILE NAME
            V_LOG_DIR varchar2(30) default 'ND_GANJIS_LOG_DIR'; --LOG DIRECOTY

        begin

            V_F_IS_OPEN := utl_file.is_open(GM_LOG_FILE); 

            if not V_F_IS_OPEN then

              --Log File Open
          -- 32767 IS THE MAXIMUM NUMBER OF CHARACTERS PER LINE, INCLUDING THE NEWLINE CHARACTER, FOR THIS FILE.
              GM_LOG_FILE := UTL_FILE.FOPEN(V_LOG_DIR, 'NIA_PLSQL_'||to_char(sysdate, 'yyyymmdd')||'.log', 'A', 32767);

            end if;

            --LOG MSG TO BE WRITTEN TO THE LOG FILE
            V_LOG_MSG := TO_CHAR(systimestamp, 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss:ff3') ||' '|| P_MSG;

            --Output messages to a file 
            UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(GM_LOG_FILE, V_LOG_MSG);

        --Closing log file.
        if P_MODE = PV_LOG_CLOSE_MODE and utl_file.is_open(GM_LOG_FILE) then

              utl_file.fclose(GM_LOG_FILE);

        end if;

        --HERE THE EXCEPTION PART IS NOT INCLUDED, 
        --理由： PROGRAM WILL GO ON INFINITE LOOP IF SOME ERROR OCCURS HERE, BECAUSE, EACH EXCEPTION WRITES INTO
        --LOG FILE, USING THIS PROCEDURE.
       exception 

        when others then

          raise_application_error(PV_LOG_ERR_CODE, dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace||chr(10)||dbms_utility.format_error_stack||chr(10)||dbms_utility.format_call_stack, true); 

        end PROC_LOG; 

      /**
       * JAVA Interface   
       */  
      function FUNC_GET_DATA(P_OUT_CUR out SYS_REFCURSOR) 
                return varchar2 as

          V_START_TIME pls_integer;
          V_RET varchar2(32656);

        begin

          V_START_TIME := dbms_utility.get_time();
          PROC_LOG('NP_AC015_FETCH.FUNC_GET_DATA Process Start', PV_LOG_START_MODE);

          V_RET := FUNC_HEAD_STMT 
                   ||FUNC_FIRE_STMT 
                   ||GM_L ||' union '                              
                   ||FUNC_GENERAL_STMT
                   ||GM_L ||' union '                              
                   ||FUNC_ACCIDENT_STMT
                   ||GM_L ||' union '                              
                   ||FUNC_LI_STMT
                   ||FUNC_END_STMT;

          PROC_LOG('SQL query:' ||GM_L|| V_RET);

          PROC_LOG('sql文作成終了: '||(dbms_utility.get_time()-V_START_TIME)/100||' sec 桁数：'||LENGTHB(V_RET), PV_LOG_CLOSE_MODE);

          PROC_LOG('NP_AC015_FETCH.FUNC_GET_DATA Cursor Open Start Digits：'||LENGTHB(V_RET), PV_LOG_START_MODE);

          /*open P_OUT_CUR FOR 
            select 'FROM NIA PACKAGE'
            from   DUAL;
            */
          open P_OUT_CUR FOR V_RET;


          PROC_LOG('Process end'||(dbms_utility.get_time()-V_START_TIME)/100||' sec ', PV_LOG_CLOSE_MODE);

          return V_RET;

      end FUNC_GET_DATA;


      /**
       * JAVA Interface FOR AUTO and CALI
       */  
      function FUNC_GET_DATA_AUTO(P_OUT_CUR out SYS_REFCURSOR) 
                return varchar2 as

          V_START_TIME pls_integer;
          V_RET varchar2(32656);

        begin

          V_START_TIME := dbms_utility.get_time();
          PROC_LOG('NP_AC015_FETCH.FUNC_GET_DATA_AUTO Process Start', PV_LOG_START_MODE);

          V_RET := FUNC_HEAD_STMT 
                   ||FUNC_AUTO_STMT
                   ||GM_L ||' union '
                   ||FUNC_CALI_STMT
                   ||FUNC_END_STMT;

          PROC_LOG('SQL query:' ||GM_L|| V_RET);

          PROC_LOG('sql statement creation end: '||(dbms_utility.get_time()-V_START_TIME)/100||' sec 桁数：'||LENGTHB(V_RET), PV_LOG_CLOSE_MODE);

          PROC_LOG('NP_AC015_FETCH.FUNC_GET_DATA_AUTO Cursor Open Start Digits：'||LENGTHB(V_RET), PV_LOG_START_MODE);

          /*open P_OUT_CUR FOR 
            select 'FROM NIA PACKAGE'
            from   DUAL;
            */
          open P_OUT_CUR FOR V_RET;


          PROC_LOG('Process end'||(dbms_utility.get_time()-V_START_TIME)/100||' sec ', PV_LOG_CLOSE_MODE);

          return V_RET;

      end FUNC_GET_DATA_AUTO;

    end NP_AC015_FETCH;
    /
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no package functionality, however, often I use a separate schema to hold my groups of functions to keep them logically together.

Also, as far as variables are concerned, they don't work the same way either. You can use session type variables to achieve a similar result, you can also write a specific function that returns an object (array or hstore) that contains the values, especially if they were just "package level hard coded constants".

```
create or replace function mypkg.get_global(name varchar) returns varchar as $$
declare
retval varchar;
begin
  begin
   select current_setting('MYPKG.'||name) into retval;
   exception when others then return null;
  end;
return retval;
end;
$$ language plpgsql stable;

create or replace function mypkg.set_global(name varchar, val varchar) returns varchar as $$
declare
retval varchar;
begin
  begin
   select set_config('MYPKG'||name, var, false);
   exception when others then return null;
  end;
return retval;
end;
$$ language plpgsql stable;
```

Now this provides a method to set and get variables, but they are per session so you need a method to initialize the variables at the beginning. This is useful when wanting to get the current app user, permissions, etc-- the init function can be ran when the person logs in to the app or something.. you'll have to decide what's best here.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Will let you know once it will works.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for "stored procedures". Postgres indeed also had that concept and offers several alternative languages.

It is utterly impossible to"convert" the original Oracle packages. You will need to reimplement the code. This would also be a good point in time to think about moving that logic into the application.

Comment: yeah, postgresql stored code is is funadmentally different to oracle stored code.  procedures may need to be re-designed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.